# Video.js + Can't change color of progress bar

Tags: colors, progress, video.js

This player (video.js) works, which is more than I can say for the other player I attempted to integrate into my site. THANK YOU! However, I am running into a problem with the how the style appears in IE that I can't seem to resolve. No matter what I try I can not override the current progress bar color. I need the color to match a certain color in my website. However, all I get now is purple.

I have tried changing the CSS class .vjs-play-progress (and changed the background attribute). I have even tried placing a CSS snippet created from the video.js front page custom video creator into the head of the page that my video resides on. Still nothing. I tried adding **!important** after the color specification

```
.vjs-play-progress {background: #63CADF !important;}
```

But no dice there either.

Here is where the player currently resides:

http://www.myvisitreup.com/videoOverview.html

Please help as I have exhausted my solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data-setup` attribute is broken so it's actually showing the native controls, not the custom HTML controls. (In the error console you'll see 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse(): invalid or malformed JSON data')

```
data-setup='{controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto"}'
```

should be

```
data-setup='{"controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto"}'
```

(missing quote before controls)